# How to get OAuth 2.0 access token using refresh token in scala

Tags: scala, oauth-2.0, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to get OAuth2.0 access token using refresh token in scala .

Comment: This kind of questions is out of topic here, but you can use any of the [oauth-2 libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=oauth-2+library+scala&oq=oauth-2+library+scala&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160l3.13507j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for scala or java. Or just roll your own: your provider should have some documentation for a token request.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code using the HttpsURLConnection, without any libraries

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class Sample_OAuth {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Sample_OAuth outhDriver = new Sample_OAuth();
        outhDriver.sendRefreshTokenRequestWithOnlyHeader(null);

    }

    /**
     * Send refresh token request to 3rd party with client cred either in body or
     * request header.
     * 
     * @param conn
     * @param mapListTagToMetaDataName
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */

    private Map<String, Object> sendRefreshTokenRequestWithOnlyHeader(Map<String, String> mapListTagToMetaDataName)
            throws Exception {
        String tokenUrl = "https://xyz.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/token-request";
        URL url = new URL(tokenUrl);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        appendURLParam(stringBuilder, "grant_type", "refresh_token", true);
        appendURLParam(stringBuilder, "refresh_token",              "ver:2-hint:2065896170862-did:1003-ETMsDgAAAYWAOC1cABRBRVMvQ0JDL1BLQ1M1UGFkZGluZwEAABAAEDu3hgX2UvrDbaMif7uC+ygAAADwoZhxL+aOCvvsmNh0wy0FdNGuDRLCtOq7iQTsZPPmfkRZJnkj3nXgKDxTFeFOmty4ej/O6Fsf17HfNvKdLrqfN3V29FkFQ5S+FktFIznTSjtd7+xaMS+sPEAyey2SFfbSyMvrknjq9F+CQZ50H181OO8Ak4v1uW4ON9Q1UBRd9ywM2Yg5g59hPgy90jtAW0DPQ8gvfAwRJCgg2wzV7tXrQ1H2TQhFEkQH418s5pSNB5V6BSW0fFqOUW3O8X4MmHcWcpTbghZ5aga8+dSKSR8jd2KMmfawyXMdkIYdWEsrpcJozuYDAjFwIT1lkqLxqBnuABQIbwjao0KeWXYU3sYanTb0WoR4Ng==",
                false);
        String clientRequestType = "Basic Auth Header";

        return sendOAuthRequestWithHeader(mapListTagToMetaDataName, url, stringBuilder.toString());

    }

    private static void appendURLParam(StringBuilder stringBuilder, String name, String value, boolean appendAmpersand)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        /*
         * if (StringUtil.isNullOrEmptyTrim(name) ||
         * StringUtil.isNullOrEmptyTrim(value)) { //log.error(String.
         * format("Either Auth attr name : %s or value : %s is Null or empty", name,
         * value)); return; }
         */
        stringBuilder.append(name);
        stringBuilder.append("=");
        stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        //stringBuilder.append(value);
        if (appendAmpersand) {
            stringBuilder.append("&");
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Object> sendOAuthRequestWithHeader(Map<String, String> mapListTagToMetaDataName, URL url,
            String postBody) throws Exception {
        String clientId = "S0RpOorCRUQOqVncoxc8fXUO22A=";
        String client_secret = "MHTOaEmQeLB359K+kEAs/+2ow4AcmqD5/ABckC4E2fQ=";
        clientId = clientId + ":" + client_secret;

        // Should not be MIME-encode since value is used as a HTTP header and MIME adds
        // new lines if over 76 characters
        String value = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(clientId.getBytes());
        return sendOAuthRequest(url, postBody, value);
    }


    private Map<String, Object> sendOAuthRequest(URL url, String postBody, String authorizationHeader) throws Exception {
        HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        if (notNullOrEmptyTrim(authorizationHeader)) {
            urlConn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authorizationHeader);
        }
        return sendAccessTokenRequest(urlConn, postBody);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getToken(String tokenUrl, String requestBody, String authorizationHeader)
            throws Exception {

        // LOG.info("Request : getToken "+ tokenUrl);
        URL url = new URL(tokenUrl);
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        if (null != authorizationHeader && !authorizationHeader.isEmpty()) {
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authorizationHeader);
        }
        return sendAccessTokenRequest(urlConnection, requestBody);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> sendAccessTokenRequest(HttpsURLConnection urlConn, String postBody) throws Exception {
        // Write to input stream
        try {
            //optional
            enableAllSSLCert(urlConn);
            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            //optional
            urlConn.setHostnameVerifier((name, session) -> true);
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(postBody);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            int responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
            InputStream is = null;

            // LOG.info(" response code is:" + responseCode);
            if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode < 400) {
                is = urlConn.getInputStream();
            } else {
                // LOG.error("Error, sendOAuthRequest response code is:" + responseCode);
                is = urlConn.getErrorStream();
            }
            // Read response
            String response = null;
            if (null != is) {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while (true) {
                    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if (line == null) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        stringBuilder.append(line);
                    }
                }
                response = stringBuilder.toString();
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            // Logging in case of error
            if (responseCode != 200) {
                // LOG.error("Get Token error response : " + response);
            }
            System.out.println(response);
            Map<String, Object> retValue = new HashMap<>();
            retValue.put("errorCode", responseCode);
            retValue.put("token", response);
            return retValue;
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            // LOG.info(" Exception while getting Access Token:", exp);
            throw exp;
        }
    }

    public static boolean notNullOrEmptyTrim(String str) {
        return !isNullOrEmptyTrim(str);
    }

    public static boolean isNullOrEmptyTrim(String s) {
        return s == null || s.trim().isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * Enable https client for all SSL cert
     * 
     * @param urlConn
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     */
    private void enableAllSSLCert(HttpsURLConnection urlConn) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new TrustAllTrustManager() }, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // Create all-trusting host name verifier
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = (hostname, session) -> true;
        urlConn.setHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    }

    /**
     * Override Trust All trust manager
     */
    private class TrustAllTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```